# Introducing the login required decorator on my pagelogin view

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

How can i protect the the login_dash.html page that am redirected on login after being successful. For now am not sure where to apply the @login_required decorator since i redirect to an html page. Any help/contribution from the community is highly appreciated.

Below is my views code snippet:

```
def logins(request):

context =RequestContext(request)

if request.method == 'POST':
    username = request.POST['username']
password = request.POST['password']

user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
if user is not None:
        # Is the account active? It could have been disabled.
        if user.is_active:
            # If the account is valid and active, we can log the user in.
            # We'll send the user back to the homepage.
            login(request, user)
            return render(request,'login-dash.html')

        #if accounts.accttype == BUSINESS:
            #return render_to_response('business.html')

        #else: 

            #return render_to_response('login-dash.html')           

        else:
            # An inactive account was used - no logging in!
            messages.success(request, "Go to your email and activate the account") 
            return HttpResponse("Your  account is disabled.")
    else:
        # Bad login details were provided. So we can't log the user in.
        print "Invalid login details: {0}, {1}".format(username, password)
        return HttpResponse("Invalid login details supplied.")

# The request is not a HTTP POST, so display the login form.
# This scenario would most likely be a HTTP GET.
else:
    # No context variables to pass to the template system, hence the
    # blank dictionary object...
    #transaction_list = get_list_or_404(transactions)
    messages.success(request, "You have succefully logged in to your quickpay account.") 
    transaction_list ={"transactions": transactions.objects.all()}

    #yes = Picture.objects.filter(vote='yes').count()
    return render(request,'login-dash.html', transaction_list)
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: write the errors or expectations, or atleast the thing that you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: why not use ```if user.is_authenticated():``` where you need ?

Comment: samone can just hardtype in the url /logins and still land on the logins page yet its sapposed to be for successfully logged in users. Remember aam returning      return render(request,'login-dash.html')

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `@login_required` only on the views for which you want only the logged-in people to see.

For example, you don't need `@login_required` for login view as you want people to be able to login,

```
def user_login(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        password = request.POST.get('password')

        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)

        if user:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/app/')
            else:
                return HttpResponse("Your account is disabled.")
        else:
            print "Invalid login details: {0}, {1}".format(username, password)
            return HttpResponse("Invalid login credentials.")
    else:
        return render(request, 'app/login.html', {})
```

But for logout, you only want people to see logout only when they are logged in.

```
@login_required
def user_logout(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/app/')
```

So, plan what needs `@login_required` and what doesn't.

Comment: am redirecting successfully logged in users to login_dash.html . The problem is that guys can just type in the url(/logins) and still land on that  page

Comment: Can you be more specific? What happens? When users type /login_dash, they reach the dash page? Or when users type /login, they reach where? Please be more specific

Comment: You know that you can add a parameter to `@login_required` also. Make it like this: `@login_required(login_url='/app/login/')` Then it will redirect you to  login page.

Comment: how can i protect the logins view in simple terms. Because when i add the  @login_required decorator, it just keeps returning the loginpage

Comment: how can it just keeps returning the loginpage even for successfully logged in users.  i protect the logins view in simple terms. Because when i add the  @login_required decorator,

Comment: Why do you need to protect the login view?

Comment: You DON'T have to put `@login_required` on login view.

Comment: but how will i protect the tempalte page login-dash.html, after successful login. Because                         if user.is_active:
            # If the account is valid and active, we can log the user in.
            # We'll send the user back to the homepage.
            login(request, user)
            return render(request,'login-dash.html')

Comment: I don't know what you want to say. Please state your problem elaborately.